# How to distinguish greater than less than '<' '>' from generic '<>' in yacc

Tags: bison, yacc

example:

```
a < getBoolNum<int>(a < getNum<int>())
```

yacc:

```
translation_unit
    : expression
    {}
    ;
expression
    : additive_expression GT additive_expression
    {}
    | additive_expression LT additive_expression
    {}
    | expression GT additive_expression
    {}
    | expression LT additive_expression
    {}
    ;
additive_expression
    : function_call
    {}
    | IDENTIFIER
    {}
    ;
function_call
    : IDENTIFIER LT IDENTIFIER GT LP argument_list RP // identifier < identifier > ( expression, expression )
    {}
    ;
argument_list
    : IDENTIFIER
    {}
    | function_call
    {}
    | expression
    {}
    | argument_list COMMA IDENTIFIER
    {}
    | argument_list COMMA function_call
    {}
    | argument_list COMMA expression
    {}
    ;
```

conflicts: 3 shift/reduce

State 1 conflicts: 1 shift/reduce

State 19 conflicts: 1 shift/reduce

State 25 conflicts: 1 shift/reduce

```
state 1

    7 additive_expression: IDENTIFIER .
    8 function_call: IDENTIFIER . LT IDENTIFIER GT LP argument_list RP

    LT  shift, and go to state 6

    LT        [reduce using rule 7 (additive_expression)]
    $default  reduce using rule 7 (additive_expression)
```

How to distinguish greater than less than '<' '>' from generic '<>' in yacc

Comment: `<>` is meaningless', as is 'greater than less than'. Just don't allow it. I've only ever seen it used as 'not equal'. There is no ambiguity, as there is there is nothing for it to be ambiguous with.

Comment: And why are you specifying both `additive_expression GT additive_expression` and `expression GT additive_expression`?

Comment: It doesn't make sense just to test the syntax. The complete code is too long.

Comment: It doesn't make any sense *not* to 'just test the syntax', wherever that suggestion may have come from. Not from me. You haven't answered anything you've been asked here.